# How to find longest sequence of a character (repeating) in a string array?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string like : aabccdddddeeeacdd

I want my program to return the length of longest sub string of a same character like this string should return (5 = length of substring of d),

Other lengths are :

- a = 2,1
- b = 1
- c = 2,1
- d = 5,2
- e = 3

So longest length if of d.

My Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char flag;
    vector<int> v;
    int init = 0,count; // init for checking first character in loop
    string s = "aabbbcccdddddeeeaacc";
    count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(init == 0){
            flag = s[i];
            count++;
            init = 1;
        }
        else{
            if(s[i] == flag){
                count++;
            }

            else{
                flag = s[i];
                v.push_back(count);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<*max_element(v.begin(),v.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have something in mind?Let us know.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did your attempt work, or not work? What problems do you have with your attempt? You *have* [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and know how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I thought about doing a for loop and then when any character occurs then give flag a unique value and increment a counter as long as some other character does not occur and then store counts in an array and find the max value.

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work, I'm still trying I will update my code soon if it works.

Comment: Start with an array of integers of size 26.

Comment: @ZDF `"aabbb9999"`

Comment: @MichaelGeary "I have a string like : aabccdddddeeeacdd"

Comment: @ZDF Are you suggesting OP should write code that only works when the string consists purely of lowercase ASCII letters?

Comment: Wait a second let me upload my code.

Comment: In any case, you don't need an array of lengths at all. You are only interested in finding the longest run, so each time you find a new run, you compare its length with the currently longest run. If the new run is shorter, keep on going. If the new run is longer, save its start and end as the longest run and keep on going. You could do the whole thing with four variables, let's call them `bestStart`, `bestEnd`, `currentStart`, and `currentEnd`, where each of these is an array index.

Comment: @MichaelGeary He is, obviously, a beginner. Things should not be harder.

Comment: I just uploaded my code, can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting 4 as output

Comment: Start with all four of those variables set to `0`. Then increment `currentEnd` until it reaches a non-matching character. If `currentEnd - currentStart` is greater than `bestEnd - bestStart`, then set `bestStart = currentStart` and `bestEnd = currentEnd`. Then (whether the length was greater or not), set `currentStart = currentEnd` and continue. Stop when you reach the zero terminator, and `bestStart` points to the longest run and `bestEnd - bestStart` is its length. I may have an off-by-one error in here somewhere, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: @MichaelGeary "In any case..." Correct.

Comment: Your sure its correct? I Should be getting 5 as output no?

Comment: Great Idea Michael, I;ll try to implement it now

Comment: I've changed my code a bit it seems to work now.

Comment: Also note that the names I used for `bestEnd` and `currentEnd` may be a bit confusing - that's the possible off-by-one error I mentioned. Each of these should be the index of the first non-matching character. For example, after you scan through the first two characters of your "aabcc..." string, `currentStart` will be 0 and `currentEnd` will be `2`, the index of the non-matching `b` character.

Comment: I tried a solution by @GauravSehgal It seems to work.

Comment: @MichaelGeary thanks for your suggestion it seems to work too but its a little bit complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int longest = 0;
    string s = "aabbbcccdddddeeeaacc";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length();){
        char current = s[i];
        int currLen = 0;
        for(;i<s.length() && current == s[i]; ++i)
            ++currLen;
        if(currLen > longest)
            longest = currLen ;
    }

    cout<<longest;

    return 0;
}
```

This is a little simpler approach.

On a sidenote - did you try using regex? something simple like this `(.)\1+` could do all the work for you. Check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/yg8HEe/1)

Comment: This seems to work but are you sure its efficient? You are using 2 for loops, it seems small and easy although and how can i use regex in c++??

Comment: I'm sorry i haven't used regex in c++.

Comment: This is not 2 loops. It is 2 for statements, but they are just 2 parts of a single iteration over the string, so it is basically just one loop.

Comment: Are you testing a char outside the string length in the inner loop?

Comment: @K.Kirsz Hey Its great you solved it for last characters too, can you help me refactor my code for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string str;
    getline(std::cin, str);

    int i = 0;
    size_t str_size = str.size();
    std::pair<char, int> max = {' ', 0};

    while (i < str_size) {
        int j = i;
        while (str[++j] == str[i])
            ;
        if (j - i > max.second)
            max = {str[i], j - i};
        i = j;
    }

    std::cout << max.first << std::endl << max.second;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do explain how it works and why this is good. It may help people looking for answers.

Answer (score -1):

This solution seems to work,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char flag;
    vector<int> v;
    int init = 0,count; // init for checking first character in loop
    string s = "aaaaaaabbbcccddddddeeeaacc";
    count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(init == 0){
            flag = s[i];
            count++;
            init = 1;
        }
        else{
            if(s[i] == flag){
                count++;
            }

            else{
                flag = s[i];
                v.push_back(count);
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<*max_element(v.begin(),v.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Can i do something to optimize this approach, 
I will try to implement
@MichaelGeary solution with bestStart and End too.
Thanks guys for all this help.

Edit:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char flag;
    int max;
    int init = 0,count; // init for checking first character in loop
    string s = "aaaaaaabbbcccddddddeeeeeeeeeeaacc";
    count = 0;
    max = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(init == 0){
            flag = s[i];
            count++;
            init = 1;
        }
        else{
            if(s[i] == flag){
                count++;
            }

            else{
                flag = s[i];
                if(count > max){
                    max = count;
                }
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<max;

    return 0;
}
```

This solution without array seems to work,
Thanks @GauravSehgal for the suggestion :)

Comment: You don't need to store the count in array.Just store the maximum `count` encountered on the go.

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal Thanks a lot for the suggestion :) It seems to work fine

Comment: Always test border-cases of your code, for instance, the last group is not counted.

Comment: Yeah Right @Adrian Maire i haven't thought about that, can you please help me with what changed do i need to make?

Comment: @BugAdder Just do the `if(count > max){max = count;}` part in each iteration, not just inside the `else`. It shoud fix the last group problem.

Comment: @K.Kirsz Thanks a lot buddy. You really helped me a lot :)